# nodejs mysql and angularjs in electron

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron

I'm using electron and angularjs 1.

how get data from mysql and pass them to view?

I tried this but doesn't work :(.

The problem is that how to send results to `this.products` which is used in view.

My code is this:

```
angular.module('accountingApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
function () {
con.query('SELECT * FROM `products`',function(err, rows){
        if (err) throw err;
        // How pass `rows` to this.products
    })  }]);
```